# TIP: in C++, having a method where "this" is not used is not good design

Tags: c++, function, pointers, methods, virtual

Under the hood, a C++ method of a class is like a C function whose first parameter is an instance of the class - or struct.

For example:

```
void Foo::Do();
```

would be equivalent to this declaration in C:

```
void Do(Foo* this);
```

Hence, using a member m_someMember from within a method is like using this->m_someMember from inside the C function.

After so many years of C/C++ programming experience, I just recently asked myself: *What if I call a method from an instance pointer that is NULL???*

My guess was: *If the method refers to no member at all, when why would it crash?*

So I did a quick test (on a Windows platform, with Visual C++ 2008):

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {}
    virtual ~Foo() {}

    void Do();
};

void Foo::Do()
{
    cout << "Calling 'Do' for " << this << endl;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.Do();

    Foo* pNullFoo = 0;
    pNullFoo->Do();

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives an output like:

```
Calling 'Do' for 0038FE5C
Calling 'Do' for 00000000
```

This could be an hassle when doing post-mortem debugging of a crash over an instance pointer that is null. You might think that this method cannot be called if this is invalid.

On the other hand, if the method is declared virtual:

```
virtual void Foo::Do() { ... }
```

Then the line:

```
pNullFoo->Do();
```

will produce an page fault exception. Why? Because instances of a class with virtual methods have a pointer to the vtable to the child class virtual methods they belong to.
So the first thing the compiler would do is to make pNullFoo to access its vtable member, then bang!

In conclusion, this is better design to have non contextual functions like Do be implemented as procedural routines than methods, unless they are virtual.

Comment: They're both undefined behaviour. Don't change your design because some idiot user calls a member function on a null pointer.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: One of the possible outcomes of undefined behavior is to work like you'd expect. That still doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @Chris: We sometimes do change designs to make certain classes of bug easier to detect.

Answer (score 4):

Calling a member function on a NULL pointer invokes undefined behavior. Undefined doesn't mean it's going to crash, nor does it mean it's going to do the right thing - it's *undefined*. Anything could happen.

The only time I've seen this in production code is with Microsoft's `CWnd::GetSafeHWND` function. But since they wrote the compiler, they can get away with it.

Answer (score 2):

The proper design for member functions that don't need to access any member data is to have them defined as static:

```
static void Do();
```

Then call it like:

```
Foo::Do();
```

And you don't even need to have an object or a pointer to do that.

Comment: Not necessarily.  You don't see STL containers implementing `end()` as a static member, even though for several of them it doesn't use the target object in any way.  For consistency, they use a non-static member function anyway.

Comment: Of course you can do it. It is a question of design. But if you want to avoid that "undefined" behavior, then static is the way to go and not implementing it as virtual.

Comment: There are functions designed to be called on an object, even though they don't use any member data of that object.  "undefined" behavior is avoiding *by providing a valid target object*.  You don't need `static` to avoid undefined behavior.  Again, `end()` is a classic example, since end iterators are often just magic values and not computed from the member data of the container.

Comment: Your question (if we can consider it a question?!) is about being able to provide an invalid target object! So if the solution is to provide a valid target object, why do you wrote this in the first place? I just presented another valid design. Take it or live it...

Comment: What "my question"?  I didn't ask a question.  (Well, actually my comment was "Did you have a question?" which is a question.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It looks like you think you're replying to PLemoine?

Comment: Oops... :) But then again, it is a question of design...